# Rails nested attributes with simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a households model and the household can have many visits to my agency. I have a new visit view (listed as a view under visits) that has the following code to enter the information about the visits. Below is just a snippet that has the nested attributes for the visit.

I am using strong parameters and in the households model I have the visits_attributes set (and it was working properly when I had something similar set up when I had the view listed under households)

```
= simple_form_for household do |h|
  - @visit = household.visit.new
  = h.simple_fields_for @visit do |h|


Unpermitted parameters: visit
Unpermitted parameters: visit
```

Obviously it is not working because visit is not permitted - visit is apparently the @visit instance variable I put in simple form to create a blank form

This isn't right how should I set this up?

Comment: You want to embed Visit.new form to housholds#show action? otherwise its little sense to use nested_attributes if you want Visit.new under visits#new action. What is your ultimate goal doing what you do?

Comment: Great Point I started embedding the visit in the household. But I am thinking now it should be reversed I am creating a visit not a household - the household information is just for reference but I have more household information than visit information to display

Comment: You did right embedding visits in the HH. I assume one HH can have many visits, if this is right, than you can make nested attributes for visitors. The point is that you dont need do that in the houshold/new.html.erb but in the houshold/show.html.erb. This way first you create HH and than you can easily assign visit to HH you want. I can elaborate this in answer if you need.let me know.cheers.

Comment: I re thought this some and actually posted a different, hopefully more focused question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235724/rails-routing-to-new-associated-model  -