# Rails Routing to New associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, simple-form

I have an App that has Households that visit my agency and I am logging each time a household visits. I select the household in the households index and open the visit view which is in the  visits model in my index to select a household and create a new visit I have teh following code on my index view for households:

```
 = link_to  'Visit', new_household_visit_path(household), class: 'btn btn-mini'
```

Rake Routes Shows:

```
new_household_visit GET    /households/:household_id/visits/new(.:format)    visits#new
```

This take me to a form with the following url:

```
  http://localhost:3000/households/5/visits/new
```

I Have a simple form set up at this view as so:

```
= simple_form_for [household, visit], url: new_household_visit_path  do |f|
%h2 Household: #{household.name}
```

Now when I fill in the form and try to save with a submit  I get:

```
 No route matches [POST] "/households/5/visits/new"
```

Now I did notice that in Rake Routes I have a GET but not a POST but I am still not sure what my problem is?

Routes.rb shows:

```
  resources :households do
    resources :visits
    resources :neighbors
  end
```

I changed my simple form call to:

```
= simple_form_for [household, visit], url: household_visits_path do |f|
```

I am creating my form but on saving I get the error:

```
Required parameter missing: household
```

the log shows:

```
Started POST "/households/8/visits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-22 07:58:34 -0400
Processing by VisitsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"HCivpI4SLQTzj2VlwibssNEw/o69jIt4J54/hjVPgJ4=", "visit"=>{"visited_on(1i)"=>"2013", "visited_on(3i)"=>"22", "visited_on(2i)"=>"6", "neighbor_id"=>"46", "starch"=>"Beans", "cereal"=>"", "option1"=>"", "items_received"=>"", "notes"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Visit", "household_id"=>"8"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
      (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Neighbor Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "neighbors".* FROM "neighbors" WHERE "neighbors"."id"  = 46 ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered visits/_new.html.haml (129.7ms)
  Rendered visits/new.html.haml within layouts/application (136.2ms)
  Rendered text template (0.0ms) 
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1126ms (Views: 7.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I believe I am getting close

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using standard routes such as:

```
resources :households do
  resources :visits
end
```

Then you want to be posting to `household_visits_path` instead of `new_household_visit_path`.

If you run `rake routes` you'll probably get something similar to this:

```
    household_visits GET    /households/:household_id/visits(.:format)          visits#index
                     POST   /households/:household_id/visits(.:format)          visits#create
 new_household_visit GET    /households/:household_id/visits/new(.:format)      visits#new
edit_household_visit GET    /households/:household_id/visits/:id/edit(.:format) visits#edit
     household_visit GET    /households/:household_id/visits/:id(.:format)      visits#show
                     PUT    /households/:household_id/visits/:id(.:format)      visits#update
                     DELETE /households/:household_id/visits/:id(.:format)      visits#destroy
```

You'll notice that the only one accepting a POST request is `household_visits`. `new_household_visit` is only used to GET the form.

Comment: I revised my question to show my routes.rb and the result after using household_visits